# '_route' is defined but never used

Tags: angular, eslint

I am getting an error while validating typescript.

> '_route' is defined but never
> used.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

I added the following rules to my **eslintrc** file:

```
"rules": {
  "no-unused-vars": "off",
  "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error"
}
```

But it didn't help me in any way.

**auth.guard.ts:**

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
    constructor(private _auth: AuthService, private router: Router) { }
    canActivate(_route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, _state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
           ...
    }
    canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.canActivate(route, state);
    }
}
```

**.eslintrc.json:**

```
...
      "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
          "error"
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/component-class-suffix": [
          "error",
          {
            "suffixes": [
              "Component",
              "Page"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ]
      }
...
```

Comment: Could you try to change `_route` -> `_`